# Python: how to reshape a dataframe based on a condition?`

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
df
     Name   Val1   Val2
0    Mark    0      3
1    Mark    2      3
2    Mark    5      6
3    Mark    7      8
```

I would like to have something like this

```
df
       Name  Val1_0    Val1_1   Val1_2   Val1_3  Val2_0    Val2_1   Val2_2   Val2_3
0      Mark    0          2       5        7       3         3        6        8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `set_index()`,`reset_index()` and `unstack()`:

```
out=df.set_index('Name',append=True).unstack(0)
```

Finally :

```
out.columns=out.columns.map(lambda x:'_'.join(map(str,x)))
out=out.reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
    Name    Val1_0  Val1_1  Val1_2  Val1_3  Val2_0  Val2_1  Val2_2  Val2_3
0   Mark    0       2        5        7       3       3       6      8
```

Comment: you can avoid the reset_index with ``df.set_index('Name', append=True)``

Comment: @AnuragDabas thank you for your answer. However I would like to have the increasing number of the information and not the index information after the `_`. Please see the revised question

Comment: @emax I was trying to do but you asked another question...@BENY got you ***;)***

Comment: @emax edited your question to previous version so that it won't marked as duplicate